# How to launch email client from my app in such a manner that I could see inbox, sent items etc

Tags: android, android-intent

When I launch email client from my application, a compose window of email client gets opened but when I launch like this, I am unable to see inbox, sent items etc...

In short how to launch email client from app exactly like launching from desktop?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in short how to launch email client from app exactly like launching from desktop..

There is no standard Intent for this, sorry.

Comment: @manju: As I said, there is no standard `Intent` for this, sorry. For that matter, there is no standard "email client".

Comment: that has to be the most useless answer ever

Comment: it's true apparently though. maybe the answer could be amended in that there is no concept for a standard emal reading client.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this from your activity object:

it will not necessarily take you to the Inbox directly but it will open the email application:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.email");
startActivity(intent);
```

Samer Alameer

Answer (score -1):

Just in case anyone else gets here with the same question, there is a solution.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.google.android.email/com.android.email.activity.Welcome"));
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
startActivity(intent);
```

You can get the component name from LogCat. The only problem is, I think, if the user uses another application for email.