# Android read mail intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Android documents starting the email intent for sending emails with Intent.ACTION_SEND.

Is there an intent which directs the user to reading his email, or which launches the default email application?

The application that launches the "read mail" intent would get no access to the email data.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204073/how-to-launch-email-client-from-my-app-in-such-a-manner-that-i-could-see-inbox-se asked only 5 minutes ago...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there an intent which directs the user to reading his email, or which launches the default email application?

There is no standard `Intent` for this, sorry.

Comment: Yes, it appears that this is the case. But is there maybe some way to launch the Google Mail application, if it is installed on the device?

Comment: @ogh: Not in any documented and supported fashion.

Comment: Google-Now all shows "view email" option for some events. You might want to intercept the intent to find a way, but that would be unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this, it works for me

```
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.email");
    startActivity(intent);
```