# do not redirect to compose email activity on notification click

Tags: android

what i would like to achieve is to inform the user that a new email has been sent to his account when he clicks on a notification...the problem is that using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));

    //intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    //startActivity(intent);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

when i click in each suggested app provided(Gmail, Email) from the chooser dialog i am redirected to each app's compose email activity..but i would like to get to my email list activity or just start each app and not being redirected to compose activity...is there a way to fix it?

Comment: The intent action is ACTION_SENDTO. This is why its going to compose activity.

Comment: using also ACTION_SEND its starting compose activity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard intent to open the email list activity.

[How to launch email client from my app in such a manner that I could see inbox, sent items etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204073/how-to-launch-email-client-from-my-app-in-such-a-manner-that-i-could-see-inbox)